# How to block specific user push notification in parse iOS app?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am working on a iOS chatting app by use parse as backend service. If user blocks another user, how to prevent the push notifications? Is that possible to filter this push notification in parse side?

Really appreciate in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details as to the structure of your application so the community can be of more assistance. This is a very wide open question and can be solved many ways.

Comment: How about this use case: in the messenger app, a user sends a message object, and a push notification through a PFCloud callFunctionInBackgound.  The receiving user blocked the sender.  This already removed their "Relationship" but it doesn't stop the notification from being sent.

Comment: To further explain, the Blocked Usernames are stored in an array the user created.  iOS Dev, not sure how to fetch the array, or compare usernames to find if blocked in JS (Parse Cloudcode). @JamesParker

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to block a push notification from being sent to a user that blocked the sender.  It really depends on how you handle the blocking of the user.

You could, for instance, add a blockedUsernames array to each user.  If you did this, you could block the push notification from being sent in the first place, by cross checking this blocked users array against the users it is being sent to.

```
// CHECK FOR BLOCKED USERS

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser]; // user sending push
    PFUser *sendPushToUser = //user receiving the push

// Get array of blocked users
    NSMutableArray *blockedUsersArray = sendPushToUser[@"blockedUsers"];

    BOOL blocked = false;
    for (NSString *username in blockedUsersArray) {
        if ([username isEqualToString:currentUser.username]) {
            blocked = true;
        }
    }

     // If the user isn't blocked, send push
    if (blocked == false) {

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendPushToUser" 
    // more cloud code to handle the notification...
```

You could also block the push notification in the Parse Cloud Code, with some JS.